# Plotting and using NIntegrate

Tags: plotting

Mathematica is throwing error messages when I try to plot what I want. As a minimal working example of this problem, the following code runs fine:

```
test[x_] := NIntegrate[Sin[x - Pi/2] Exp[-xp^2/2], {xp, -Pi, Pi}]
```

`Plot[test[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

But if I decide to do a polar plot

```
PolarPlot[test[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I get the error message: "NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand -E^(-(xp^2/2)) Cos[x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,3.14159}}. >>"

but eventually I get the plot I'm looking for. I'm wondering why PolarPlot has difficulty, while Plot does not.

Comment: Classic problem: see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/29734). Define your function with `NumericQ`: `Clear[test]; test[x_?NumericQ] := ...`.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem.